# TyperError while inserting list into mongodb via python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, mongodb, telethon

```
for chat in chats:
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat, offset_date=datetime.date(2023, 1, 31), reverse=True):
        my_list.append(message)
collection.insert_many(my_list)
```

Above code should be able to insert list into mongodb but it is giving following error.

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

how code should be instead of what it is.

Comment: what's the data type of message?

Comment: @Kulasangar data type of message is showing "telethon.tl.patched.Message" while data type of my_list is showing "list"

Comment: cos basically you should be passing a list of dictionaries into the **insert_many** from what I see in the examples. Could you try to convert that Message object into dict and see?

Comment: @Kulasangar well, i added a code "variable= dict(message)" but it is giving error like  'Message' object is not iterable" ... how can it be converted to dict or how list can be converted to dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try converting the message object to dict:

```
for chat in chats:
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat, offset_date=datetime.date(2023, 1, 31), reverse=True):
        my_list.append(message.to_dict()) <-- try this
collection.insert_many(my_list)
```